# How to create LIST sub partitions automatically into main RANGE partition

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am having a table with RANGE Partition on date and LIST sub partition as mentioned below.

```
CREATE TABLE REC_XXX_DATA 
( 
    XXX_ID VARCHAR2(8), 
    TEMPLATE_ID VARCHAR2(20), 
    XXX_DATE DATE 
) 
partition by RANGE(XXX_DATE) INTERVAL (numtodsinterval(7, 'DAY')) 
subpartition by list(XXX_ID)
(
partition OCT2619 values less than (TO_DATE(' 2019-10-26 23:59:59', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
(
   subpartition T360_OCT2619 values('AAA'),
   subpartition ABMC_OCT2619 values('BBB')    
) 
);
```

I am inserting 27-Oct-2019 data in column XXX_DATE Then a new RANGE partition is added to a table and its subpartition is also added with list value as DEFAULT. Hence all the data is moving into same sub partition.

My requirement is to create sub partitions automatically with actual values of XXX_ID that we are inserting.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

No. Automatic List Partitions are not supported at subpartition level up to 12cR2. I am not aware of higher versions.

If you already know the distinct values of XXX_ID column and if new values are rare for XXX_ID, you can create a subpartition template leaving a default partition for new values.

```
CREATE TABLE REC_XXX_DATA 
( 
    XXX_ID VARCHAR2(8), 
    TEMPLATE_ID VARCHAR2(20), 
    XXX_DATE DATE 
) 
partition by RANGE(XXX_DATE) INTERVAL (numtodsinterval(7, 'DAY')) 
subpartition by list(XXX_ID)
subpartition template
(subpartition AAA values('AAA'),
 subpartition BBB values('BBB'),
 subpartition XXX values(DEFAULT))
(
 partition OCT2619 values less than (TO_DATE(' 2019-10-26 23:59:59', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
 (
   subpartition AAA values('AAA'),
   subpartition BBB values('BBB'),
   subpartition XXX values(DEFAULT)
 ) 
);

insert into REC_XXX_DATA values('AAA','T1',to_date('27-oct-19','dd-mon-yy'));

select table_name, partition_name, subpartition_name, high_value 
  from user_tab_subpartitions 
 where table_name = 'REC_XXX_DATA' order by 1,2,3;
```

Output:

```
TABLE_NAME    PARTITION_NAME SUBPARTITION_NAME HIGH_VALUE
REC_XXX_DATA  OCT2619        AAA               'AAA'
REC_XXX_DATA  OCT2619        BBB               'BBB'
REC_XXX_DATA  OCT2619        XXX               DEFAULT
REC_XXX_DATA  SYS_P197962    SYS_SUBP197959    'AAA'
REC_XXX_DATA  SYS_P197962    SYS_SUBP197960    'BBB'
REC_XXX_DATA  SYS_P197962    SYS_SUBP197961    DEFAULT

select count(1) from REC_XXX_DATA subpartition(SYS_SUBP197959);--1
```